# Passing your client's X509 certificate to another server

Tags: .net, web-services, x509certificate

I am developing a web application in .net that needs to serve clients using their X509 certificates. My webapp needs to call remote webservices from another provider (government servers) that uses the x509 authentication.

I already developed and tested the page using a certificate stored in the local system using the call below:

```
GovernmentWebservice.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
    StoreLocation.LocalMachine, 
    StoreName.My, 
    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
    "MY CERTIFICATION SUBJECT NAME");
```

But this becomes a problem because I need to use the certificate sent by the client when he connected to my webpage (`Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate`). I found that the call of the remote webservice only works with certificates stored in my local machine. Anyone knows any workaround so I can use my clients' certificate to call the other webservice?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its not possible according to this other user

[Intercepting and forwarding client certificate to webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650008/intercepting-and-forwarding-client-certificate-to-webservice)

Would be glad if someone knows anything in contrary.